# How to make an arraylist with multiple enums in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to get an enum ArrayList to be able to accept a different enum.

```
enum foo {f,o,o}
enum bar {b,a,r}

ArrayList<Foo> foo = new Arraylist<>();
foo.add(bar.b); // Doesn't work
```

Sorry, if this is a bit weird.

Comment: If you want put `bar.b` in it, why is it an `ArrayList<foo>`?

Comment: You "could" make both `enums` conform to a "common" `interface`, but I can't see what benefit you'd gain, at some point, you'd need to cast them back

Comment: You can declare `foo` as `List<Enum>`. But what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: My guess is that you want an enum that has all the elements of both `Foo` (which you misspelled) and `bar` (did you mean `Bar`?). Not a good idea because there might be duplicates between them (e.g if you added `z` to both). Maybe what you really want is for your enums to have attributes, e.g. `FooBar` with a `boolean isFoo` field, or another enum `FBType {Foo, Bar}` and a `FBType type` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to *assume* that you have a sound reason for building a list that contains multiple types.  (See below for reasons why it *may not be* a good idea.)

Here's your example ... tidied up a bit

```
enum Foo {A, B, C}
enum Bar {D, E, F}

ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Bar.D);    // Doesn't work
```

In simple terms, the reason that that statement doesn't work is that `Foo` and `Bar` are distinct types.  A `Bar` instance is not a `Foo` instance.

What is the work-around?

- One possible workaround is this:

  ```
  ArrayList<Enum<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(Foo.A);
  list.add(Bar.D);
  ```

  This works because all `enum` classes are subtypes of `Enum`.

  But the downside is that you can put *any* `enum` value into the list.
- A second workaround is to declare `Foo` and `Bar` as implementing some custom interface; e.g.

  ```
  interface Thing {}
  enum Foo implements Thing {A, B, C}
  enum Bar implements Thing {D, E, F}

  ArrayList<Thing> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(Foo.A);
  list.add(Bar.D);
  ```
- A final workaround is to combine `Foo` and `Bar` into a single `enum`.

Note that solutions 2 and 3 are essentially changing the `enum` types; i.e. changing the problem.  This may not be an option for you.

---

Unfortunately, there is (currently) **no way** to declare a "union" type in Java.  For example:

```
ArrayList<Foo | Bar> list = new ArrayList<>();  // Doesn't work!!!
```

---

So why did I say this *may not be* a good idea?  Well the problem is that when you put instances of multiple types into a collection your code typically has to discriminate the different cases when you perform operations on the collection; e.g.

```
ArrayList<Enum<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Foo.A);
list.add(Bar.D);

for (Enum<?> e: list) {
   if (e instanceof Foo) {
       doSomething((Foo) e);
   } else if (e instanceof Bar) {
       doSomethingElse((Bar) e);
   } else {
       throw new SomethingUnexpectedException("...");
   }
}
```

It is better if you use the 2nd workaround, but:

- you still need to discriminate and cast if you want to access methods or attributes that are specific to one or other enum, and
- the `Thing` type is not a subtype of `Enum` so you can't call `Enum` methods on a value whose (static) type is `Thing`.